# Getting 403 error with java

Tags: java

When I pass the URL "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two" to the code below it returns JSON data.

But when I pass "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1" instead, I get 403 forbidden error.

I'm not sure what's going on. Any advice?

```
package automation_Demo_First;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class JsonReader{

    //http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1
    public String url ="http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two";
    @Test
    public void testJson() throws IOException{

        String data = getDataByJavaIO(url);
        System.out.println(data);
    }



    public String getDataByJavaIO(String url) throws IOException{
        InputStream inputstream = null;
        BufferedReader bufferreader = null;

        try{
            inputstream = new URL(url).openStream();
            bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            return readData(bufferreader);

        }catch(IOException e){
            throw e;

        }
        finally{

            closeResource(inputstream);
            closeResource(bufferreader);
        }


    }




    public String readData(Reader reader) throws IOException{

        StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while((cp=reader.read())!=-1){
            stringbuilder.append((char)cp);
        }
        return stringbuilder.toString();


    }

    public void closeResource(AutoCloseable closable){

        try{
            if(closable!=null){
                closable.close();
                System.out.println("\n" +closable.getClass().getName() + "closed ..." );
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting 403 repsonse](https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder/issues/34)

Answer (score 0):

In your `try` block,

```
try {
    inputstream = new URL(url).openStream();
    bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    return readData(bufferreader);
}
```

change it to

```
try {
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    httpCon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36");
    inputstream = httpCon.getInputStream();
    bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    return readData(bufferreader);
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889991/3903483

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
URLConnection hc = new URL(url).openConnection();
hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
inputstream = hc.getInputStream();
```

Instead of:

```
inputstream = new URL(url).openStream();
```